# React's useSelector with array of objects

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Let's say I have a reducer with the following state:

```
messages: [
    {
        "id": "94",
        "characterId": "1",
        "text": "Uhm... Who are you?",
        "cloneId": "",
        "parentId": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "92",
        "characterId": "1",
        "text": "So what's with the whole E=mc2 thing?",
        "cloneId": "",
        "parentId": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "68-1",
        "characterId": "1",
        "text": "Oh no. Even now, we only have a small glimpse of the bottom of the ocean!",
        "cloneId": "",
        "parentId": "68"
    }
]
```

How can I make the Message component representing the message with id "92" rerender only when say the object with id "92" is updated?

This approach causes a rerender whenever any of the objects in the array change :/

```
const Message = () => {
   const data = useSelector((state) => state.conversationsData.messages.find((m) => {
       return m.id == '92'
   }))
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

redux presents some solutions about this question in the [docs](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#equality-comparisons-and-updates). you can pass `shallowEqual` (or other comparison method you prefer) as second argument like:

```
import { shallowEqual, useSelector } from 'react-redux'

const Message = () => {
   const data = useSelector((state) => state.conversationsData.messages.find((m) => {
       return m.id == '92'
   }), shallowEqual)
   ...
}
```

for more complex memoize situations you can use [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) library for memoizing along with redux.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you. 2 days of scratching my head and it was so simple!

Answer (score -3):

You can use "useEffect" hook for this.

```
  const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (//check for particular message variable changes) {
    setRefresh(refresh=>!refresh)
    }
  }, [messages])


<MessageComponent refresh={refresh} />
```

With that approach message component will render only when refresh changes value

Comment: The way `useEffect` interacts with the render cycle makes this a bit 'wonky' even if it works, you shouldn't need to use it for this purpose at all.